# Nos paramos a/para ver?

Tags: vocabulario

He encontrado la frase

> Nos paramos a ver los escaparates

Sin embargo había pensado que habría sido

> Nos paramos **para** ver los escaparates

Aunque supongo que la primera es correcta, ¿La segunda también?  Y si la primera lo es, ¿Es una colocación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El DLE incluye un significado de *[parar](https://dle.rae.es/parar)* que utiliza la preposición "a":

> 20. prnl. Ejecutar una acción con atención y sosiego. *Pararse A considerar*.

Si se usa "pararse a" con este significado, no es necesario que una acción interrumpa a otra:

- Nunca me he parado a contar los escalones que tiene nuestra escalera.

La preposición "a" también se puede usar con el significado literal de "interrumpir una acción para realizar otra":

- A mitad de viaje, [paramos a comer](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=paramos%20a%20comer).

En este caso, yo no usaría la forma pronominal, aunque es posible que sea válida en vista de la acepción 11 en el DLE:

> 11. intr. Cesar en el movimiento o en la acción, no pasar adelante en ella. U. t. c. prnl.

A mi entender, la preposición *para* solo se puede usar con el significado de interrupción: se puede decir

- A mitad de viaje, (nos) paramos para comer.

pero la siguiente frase no suena bien:

- <del>Nunca me he parado para contar los escalones que tiene nuestra escalera.</del>